# Index outside the bounds of the array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, web-services, windows-forms-designer

i do get this error... please help me guys 
here's my code

```
private int getLastRowCount()
{
    return dg.Rows.Count - 1;
}
double[] minAmounts = new double[getLastRowCount()];
double[] maxAmounts = new double[getLastRowCount()];
double[] chrgeValues = new double[getLastRowCount()];
   for (int ctr = 0; (ctr <= getLastRowCount()); ctr++)
   {
        minAmounts[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[0, ctr].Value);
        maxAmounts[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[1, ctr].Value);
        chrgeValues[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[2, ctr].Value);
   }
```

Comment: Try changing (ctr <= getLastRowCount()) to (ctr < getLastRowCount()) as dg seem to be zero based index, i.e. first element has index 0 and last has count-1

Comment: using (ctr < getLastRowCount()), cant go further loop

Comment: Debug your code to find out what line generate error and why, http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: im debugging sir.. i can get the value but cant save data.. im using web services

Comment: It seems the size of minAmounts, maxAmounts or maxAmounts is less than the number you get through getLastRowCount()

Comment: i cant get the excact values of minAmounts, maxAmounts and chrgeValues.. the result is double{0} for minAmounts, maxAmounts and chrgeValues. >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the comments:

```
private int getLastRowCount()
{
    return dg.Rows.Count - 1; // let's assume this will return 5.
}
// here we declaring 3 arrays of the size 5.
double[] minAmounts = new double[getLastRowCount()];
double[] maxAmounts = new double[getLastRowCount()];
double[] chrgeValues = new double[getLastRowCount()];
// this loop will iterate 6 times: 0,1,2,3,4,5 since getLastRowRount() result to 5.
   for (int ctr = 0; (ctr <= getLastRowCount()); ctr++)
   {
        minAmounts[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[0, ctr].Value);
        maxAmounts[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[1, ctr].Value);
        chrgeValues[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[2, ctr].Value);
   }
```

Therefor, the solution is as Ceisc stated, Change this line

```
for (int ctr = 0; (ctr <= getLastRowCount()); ctr++)
```

to be:

```
for (int ctr = 0; (ctr < getLastRowCount()); ctr++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C# are zero based, and so looping to <= to getLastRowCount() takes you 1 beyond the end. You're also shortening your row count by 1 (in getLastRowCount()). Your code should be:

```
private int getLastRowCount()
{
    return dg.Rows.Count;
}

double[] minAmounts = new double[getLastRowCount()];
double[] maxAmounts = new double[getLastRowCount()];
double[] chrgeValues = new double[getLastRowCount()];

for (int ctr = 0; (ctr < getLastRowCount()); ctr++)
{
    //minAmounts[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[0, ctr].Value);
    //maxAmounts[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[1, ctr].Value);
    //chrgeValues[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[2, ctr].Value);

    // it should be [row, col]. This assumes you have at least 3 columns.
    minAmounts[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[ctr, 0].Value);
    maxAmounts[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[ctr, 1].Value);
    chrgeValues[ctr] = Convert.ToDouble(dg[ctr, 2].Value);
}
```

Although you should probably also store the value of getLastRowCount() somewhere rather than keep calling it.

Comment: I think I may have fixated on the initial array error. The indexing into the DataGrid is probably also an issue... I'll edit it.

Comment: the result of that sir is that i cant get the value.. the value of minamounts maxamounts and chargevalues are {double[0]}, {double[1]}, {double[2]}

Answer (score 0):

All the three arrays must have same capacity as that of number of rows in the dg (assuming it to be a data grid).

For ctr counter, the rows.Count - 1 is fine, but for defining the capacity of the arrays, this reduces by capacity by 1.